# My CSS is not displaying properly in Maxthon

Tags: html, css, maxthon

I am dang sure this is correct code, however it may be my browser (Maxthon). Can you tell me if this is done correctly? CSS styling of any form does not display, and I checked the element inspector and the style elements have a warning next to them and are crossed out. Lastly, the website is at this address:
[FamSite](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pdqetznmo89sx63/!)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FamSite!</title>
        <style>
            .i{
                margin: '3% 3% 3% 3%';
                padding: '2% 2% 2% 50%';
                border: '1px solid gray';
                box-shadow: '0px 0px 10px 1px silver';
                background-color: 'white'
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background:black">
        <p class="i">Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, I've already tried to fix it myself and do a web search. Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes ' from your CSS. It should be `margin: 3% 3% 3% 3%;` not `margin: '3% 3% 3% 3%';`.

```css
 .i{
                margin: 3% 3% 3% 3%;
                padding: 2% 2% 2% 50%;
                border: 1px solid gray;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px silver;
                background-color: white;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FamSite!</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background:black">
        <p class="i">Test</p>
    </body>
```